# Launchsettings.json not created using dotnet new

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-cli

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project using `dotnet` cmd, but it didn't create the default `launchSettings.json` file.

I tried adding the file manually but it still doesn't pick environment variables and command like `dotnet watch run` also don't work, is there some way to do it automatically using command line?

I used this comand: `dotnet new webapi -o projectname -n projectname`

my dotnet core version is 2.1

here's the screenshot of my created project structure:

[image: here's the screenshot of my created project structure:]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Could you share us a screen shot about your current folder structure? Try to run `dotnet --list-sdks` and share us the result. I made a test with your command and it will create the `launchSettings.json` in `Properties` folder.

Comment: @TaoZhou I added the screenshot of my project structure in the question, and running `dotnet --list-sdks` does nothing, what could be the problem

Comment: What do you mean does nothing? Where is your created `launchSettings.json`? Have you installed .net core sdk 2.1?

Comment: @TaoZhou It doesn't recognize the `dotnet --list-sdks` command, and yes when I run `dotnet --version` it gives 2.1 so that should mean I have installed the sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the .NET Core 2.2 SDKs.